# Unable to attach/download jupyter notebook to Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

I was trying to open jupyter notebook through Julia  but could not do so. I am getting the following error:

```
julia> notebook()
install Jupyter via Conda, y/n? [y]: y
[ Info: Downloading miniconda installer ...
ERROR: failed process: Process(`'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -Version 3 -NoProfile -Command "[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; (New-Object System.Net.Webclient).DownloadFile('https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe', 'C:\Users\Admin\.julia\conda\3\installer.exe')"`, ProcessExited(3221225477)) [3221225477]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a Julia issue, did you try installing conda on your own? Here's the docs [how to install conda on windows](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html).